# error after adding a chart to ASP.NET page - beginner question

Tags: asp.net, charts

In Visual Web Developer Express 2010 I created a default new ASP.NET Webapplication project. It runs OK in browser. Then I added a Chart control from Toolbox to the markup of Default.aspx (MainContent). However it fails when I try to see it in browser:

> Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd

pieces from call stack:

> System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +851
>      System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.EnsureInitialized(Boolean hardCheck) +250
>      System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.GetImageStorageMode() +24
>      System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.get_CurrentImageLocation() +40
>      System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +306

I tried adding some sample points to the chart in the markup but it still fails. I know only basics of ASP.NET but it looks strange to me that I get an exception just after adding a control so here I am.

Comment: Is there any information in the InnerException property of the exception?

Comment: @JMax: I don't know how to catch that exception - all I see is a stack trace displayed in the browser.

Comment: You can find where the error is by running the project. Before you will see the error in the browser, VS will pop up and inform you of the error. In a window at the bottom containing the currently loaded variables (the title just slipped my mind), you can expand the exception one, to reveal InnerException. Depending on how your version works, you may also be able to see the inner exception in the actual error pop up itself.

Comment: @JMax - no, there is no VS pop up, the debuger doesn't brake, so I see no variables or call stack in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had worked on Chart Controls a long time back but seems like you are missing the entries of Chart Control Assemblies in web.config.

Comment: It seems present:<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

Comment: Please follow the following link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/1dc4b352-c9a5-49dc-8f35-9b176509faa1/